# to_json works in "show" action for individual model, but not for an array of that model from has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have over-ridden my

```
 to_json(options)
```

in my Animal model.

In my show action I have

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @animal }
end
```

I have another action on this controller for getting all animals owned by a specific user.

```
  def owned_animals
    @animals = User.find(params[:user_id]).animals

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @animals }
    end
  end
```

When I call

```
/owned_animals.1.json
```

I get the old json formatting, not using my to_json override.

I'm guessing I need to override to_json in the User model to use the over_ridden animal json?

Cheers

Comment: If I do @Animals.collect {|a| a.to_json(nil)}, I get an array of the correctly formatted JSON objects, albiet with extra quotes and escaped quotes ( \" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override `as_json` instead.

[More details.](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2011/03/25/recursive-custom-to_json-in-ruby-for-arrays-of-objects-or-nested-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

`format.json { render json: @animals }` is invoking as_json, not to_json.  Try overriding as_json.

Comment: Plus 1 for correct answer, accepted @dimuch's for the additional link. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Or do

```
Animal.find_by_user(User.find(params[:id]))
```

Comment: Getting find_by_user method missing.. researching

Comment: Sorry, try Animal.find_by_user_id(params[:id])

Comment: That gives the json.. but only the first one. I have multiple Animals to a user.

Comment: Ok, then Animal.where(user_id: params[:id])

Comment: I did, same issue where the to_json is not being used

Comment: Overridden to_json* is not being used

Comment: As others have mentioned already, try override as_json instead of to_json